# Bezier Curve: Bevel Object is creating a flat surface

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm using a bezier curve and want to create a specific bevel edge shape to it in 3D.

The shape I want the bezier circle to be along its length is attached below. I created it by converting the edge of a mesh into a curve and turning it into a Bezier Curve (called Cube). I then created a Bezier curve circle and added the Cube curve from above to the Bevel Object.

The result was a perfectly flat circle when I want it to be the 3D shape of the Cube Curve I created from the mesh. 
**How do I get the Bezier Circle to bevel in the shape of the Cube Curve in 3D not flat?**

Note: When I added another smaller bezier circle to the original bezier circle path with the Bevel Object function it created a cylinder, so I assume it has something to do with the mesh conversion but I don't know what.

I have selected all points and tried Alt-T with now luck, and scaling the curves.

[image]

This was the result:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Modify the Depth and extrude values in the panel under geometry.

Comment: Furthermore, if you had previously scaled the curve down to zero in the Z-direction as a seemingly benign modification, that modification will stay with the curve and effect your results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Please rotate the shape named [Cube]  in

[Edit Mode]

90 degrees on some axis. The results should be interactive.

Comment: Thank you. I just rotated it in all planes in both Edit & Object modes. No success. I tried adding the extra Geometry factors in on each rotation change but it still stays flat.

Comment: @aussie777 The profile shape should be facing Local Z

Comment: The face is currently facing to "Y". How do I rotate it to "Z"? I did a quick Google search but couldn't figure it out. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your "Cube" curve should be a 2D Curve object, when you convert it to 2D it should maintain it's shape. If it doesn't it means the curve is not facing the correct direction and mus be rotated 90 degrees. In edit mode select all vertex and rotate in 90 degrees in the X axis by pressing R > X > 90

Comment: Excellent. That worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The shape you want to extrude along the curve must be in the local XY plane of the bevel object. This is because before extrusion takes place, the contents of the bevel object are projected to the XY plane of the bevel object. It is the same as if you had switched the Shape of the bevel object to 2D.

If your extruded shape is on the local XZ or YZ plane of the bevel object, then it will be reduced to a line when projected to the XY plane, and this line will be extruded along the curve, resulting in a flat extrusion.

The Blender 2.90 documentation will include the above explanation.